# React native image upload error with Axios :Network error

Tags: react-native, axios, multipartform-data, image-upload, general-network-error

React-Native version 0.63I am using Axios with Image upload to backend but getting error [Error:Network error ]

Comment: are you using formdata to send the image to the backend??

Comment: yes I m using form Data

export const convertToFormData = (payload) => {
  let formData = new FormData();
  Object.entries(payload).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    formData.append(key, value);
  });
  console.log('Converted formData', formData);
  return formData;
};

For while, I commented initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager())

in this file /android/app/src/main/java/com/{your_project}/MainApplication.java

NOW THIS IS WORKING PROPERLY

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue,
I guess this issue about Flipper Network.

For while, I commented
initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager())

in this file
/android/app/src/main/java/com/{your_project}/MainApplication.java

NOW THIS IS WORKING PROPERLY